# Scrollify move to specific section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, jquery-scrollify

I have 3 [Scrollify](https://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/) sections. I also have 2 buttons, I need one button to scroll to the 2nd section and the other button to scroll to the 3rd section.

**The Documentation lists this method:**

```
$.scrollify.move("#name");
```

"The move method can be used to scroll to a particular section. This can take the index of the section, or the name of the section preceded by a hash."

**Here's my broken demo:**

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/katiemoons/pen/jBVZMg?editors=0010)

**HTML**

```
<div class="section third" data-div-name="third"></div>
```

**JS**

This works:

```
$('.link2').click(function(){
  $.scrollify.next();
});
```

But this doesn't:

```
$('.link3').click(function(){
  $.scrollify.move("third");
});
```

or using "#third" or ".third"

Any ideas? Am I not using data-div-name correctly?

Comment: `data-div-name` has no relation to Scrollify. If you use Scrollify's `data-section-name` this would work how you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, it's a hashed index number not data name:

```
$('.link3').click(function(){
  $.scrollify.move("#3");
});
```

updated the demo

Comment: Yeah, as mentioned in the docs: https://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/#methods

Glad you got your issue worked out! :)

Comment: @SamiFouad Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="section third" data-section-name="third"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.link3').click(function(){
    $.scrollify.move("#third");
});
```

Code Pen: https://codepen.io/lakshmanpalitha/pen/gOorGBK